# How to change tab size in a specific file in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I know that I can change tab size in general using *Settings* -> *Code Style* -> *Python* -> *Tab size*

But what if I was given a file with tab size 2 and want to change it to 4.
Is there a fast way to do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to change the tab size, first set the tab size you want in *Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python -> Tab size*, then re-indent the code you want by selecting it and pressing `Ctrl-Alt-L`.

If you want to change the tab size in just one file, you could use `Ctrl-R` (find and replace) and replace two spaces by four (or vice versa).

Source: [PyCharm documentation - Changing Indentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/changing-indentation.html#2)

Comment: You could manage the setting in an EditorConfig config file for the project.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: After I reformatted the 2-spaced file entirely, my PyCharm kept behaving like 2-spaced...which of course broke the code every time I hit enter.

Solved it clicking '*2 spaces' in the status bar, at the bottom of the code window.
That opens a menu with several options, even a link to the settings.
In that menu just choose "4 spaces" and PyCharm is gonna start behaving like usual python (4-4-8).